# VS 2010 wstring not shown in output window

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, wstring

I want to output a wstring to the output window (I hope that is what it is called in English).

[image]

But it does not do that.

Does anybody see where I went wrong?

Comment: Try `OutputDebugStringW`. `std::wcout` goes, by default (it's whatever `stdout` is going to), to the console window.

Comment: wcout does not do that. Use OutputDebugStringW()

Comment: It would have been so nice of you if you also told me how to convert my wstring to LPCWSTR. I guess you have seen that I am newbie.

Comment: @tmighty, Look up some documentation (and I know there are quite a few duplicates of that here) and you'll find both `c_str()` and `data()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try using [`OutputDebugString()` Win32 API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

In Unicode build, which has been the default since VS2005, `OutputDebugString()` expands to `OutputDebugStringW()` (i.e. the *Unicode* UTF-16 version of the API, while the ANSI version is `OutputDebugStringA()`).

Since `OutputDebugString[W]` expects a *raw C string pointer*, you can use **`std::wstring::c_str()`** method to pass the content of the `std::wstring` to the aforementioned API:

```
// std::wstring sDebug
....
OutputDebugString( sDebug.c_str() ); // (is OutputDebugStringW() in Unicode builds)
```